# .NET OWIN Federated Authentications request for tutorial

Tags: asp.net-mvc, authentication, owin, federation

I have an MVC app suing C#/4.5 (external) that uses a given (wrote by someone that is not me) Identity Server.

I can pass in a username / password and get the OAuth.AccessTokenResponse back without issue. I can leverage the Identity Server in its current context of use.

I now have a new MVC app that needs to be able to use Active Directory (local AD) as an authentication tool and retrieve the Claims and Roles from Identity Server for the current user.

I am new to Identity server and have even less knowledge of federation.

Can anyone hit me up with a solid, recent tutorial showing me what needs to be done to Identity Server and what needs to be done to the new MVC internal application (the one that will use AD as its authentication)?

So I will have two sites that use Identity Server. External site will use Identity Server for authentication and authorization. The Internal site will use Identity Server for authorization. The authentication will be handled by AD.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you can start by watching the following quick tutorials in [Channel 9](https://channel9.msdn.com/Series/Customizing-ASPNET-Authentication-with-Identity) 
they are giving an solid foundation of knowledge, after that you can check the ready to use templates in the Visual Studio which are quite good, ah and almost to forget, you can still check the

> [Identity Server Github Tutorials](https://identityserver.github.io/Documentation/docs/overview/mvcGettingStarted.html)